# merge two not equal files in linux

Tags: shell, unix, awk, terminal, paste

I need to merge 2 files into one with 2 columns, it must be done in terminal(linux). I have googled a lot, and found solution "paste"

> paste f1 f2 > f3

But result is wrong, here's files:

f1

```
1,2.46
2,5.67
3,2.53
4,1.07
5,4.24
6,18.11
7,8.02
8,7.25
9,4.49
10,2.72
```

f2

```
1000001,1.77
1000002,3.75
1000003,1.38
1000004,4.67
1000005,3.42
1000006,2.97
1000007,9.24
1000008,4.16
1000009,1.75
1000010,5.72
1000011,2.18
1000012,2.14
1000013,2.51
1000014,1.60
1000015,2.85
```

---

```
1,2.46
    1000001,1.77
2,5.67
    1000002,3.75
3,2.53
    1000003,1.38
4,1.07
    1000004,4.67
5,4.24
    1000005,3.42
6,18.11
    1000006,2.97
7,8.02
    1000007,9.24
8,7.25
    1000008,4.16
9,4.49
    1000009,1.75
10,2.72
    1000010,5.72
    1000011,2.18
    1000012,2.14
    1000013,2.51
    1000014,1.60
    1000015,2.85
```

It's just heads of files f1 has 300000 records and f2 has 1M records. Also I know that "awk" can be used to do it. I would like to get it done using "awk"

Comment: Your files contain control-Ms. Run `dos2unix` or similar on your input files than try `paste` again. If you still have a problem then [edit] your question to show the expected output - so far you've just shown us one format of output you do NOT want.

Comment: I will use awk for my files, but "dos2unix" solved problem output was correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
    #awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1FS$2;next} {print $0,a[$1]}' f2 f1
    1,2.46 1000001,1.77
    2,5.67 1000002,3.75
    3,2.53 1000003,1.38
    4,1.07 1000004,4.67
    5,4.24 1000005,3.42
    6,18.11 1000006,2.97
    7,8.02 1000007,9.24
    8,7.25 1000008,4.16
    9,4.49 1000009,1.75
    10,2.72 1000010,5.72
```

Comment: Though it is my assumption but I think OP needs those lines too which are coming after the matching number of lines from file f1.

Answer (score 0):

@Soman: Based on assumptions which are like (you want to print the all the lines of f1 and f2 together(where first line will be of f1 and then second will be of f2 which will have a tab while printing it), then whatever extra lines are there in file f2 should be printed at one shot at last.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[FNR]=$0;next} A[FNR]{print A[FNR] ORS "\t" $0;} !A[FNR]{B[++i]=$0} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){print "\t" B[j]}}' f1  f2
```

**Explanation:** FNR==NR condition will be TRUE when first file named f1 is getting created. creating array A whose index is FNR and putting it's value as current line, where next will skip all further statements. NOW when FNR==NR condition is NOT TRUE(means second file is being read named f2) then I am checking if current line's number is present in array A then print A's value(which is from file f1) and then print a new line with tab and value of f2's current line.
Then by doing !A[FNR], I am checking if f2 file has more lines than file f1 then creating an array named B whose index is variable I(whose value is increasing) and setting it's value to current line of file f2.

In END section of awk, starting a loop which runs till the value of I and prints the values of array B which are actually those values which are only from file f2.

If you have any other requirements then kindly do mention them clearly so that we could help in same.